# What's the Kotlin generic type to capture a MutableMap and a MutableList?

Tags: generics, kotlin, collections

I want to create a function that basically returns the size of a given collection.
Specifically, I want to make it generic enough that it can work with MutableMap and MutableList.  How do I accomplish this?

I tried using `Collection<Any>` but it turns out `Map` isn't a subtype of `Collection`.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use the field `size` found both on `Collection<out E>` and `Map<K, out V>`?

```
public interface Collection<out E> : Iterable<E> {
    // Query Operations
    /**
     * Returns the size of the collection.
     */
    public val size: Int

    ...
}
```

```
public interface Map<K, out V> {
    // Query Operations
    /**
     * Returns the number of key/value pairs in the map.
     */
    public val size: Int

    ...
}
```